# change the range of yAxis ticks D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, range, data-visualization, yaxis

I need to change the range for yAxis ticks in my d3 chart. Currently, it has a range of 2M and looks like this:
[image]

The majority of data is spread between 0 and 4M. I would like to have a smaller range for ticks up until 4M and then a bigger range. So I would have ticks for 1M, 2M, 3M, 4M and then 8M, 12M, 16M. Here is the code:

```
const width = 1000;
const height = 700;
const padding = 120; // between title and svg borders
const marginTop = 120;

// Min and max for y axis for Revenue values
const maxRevenue = d3.max(dataset, (d) => d[1]);
const minRevenue = d3.min(dataset, (d) => d[1]);

const yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([minRevenue, maxRevenue])
  .range([height - padding, marginTop]);

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${padding}, 0)`)
  .call(yAxis); // if need to move the chart to the right (for yaxis)
```

Comment: The answer might be in using different scales. Check this out: https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: You want to have equally spaced ticks that don't accurately represent the numerical range of data?  While this is possible it's not an "honest" way to represent data.  Have you looked into alternatives like a broken y-axis or panel chart?

Comment: @Mark I understand, this might not be the best way to represent the data, however, there is just one record that has a high number like 16M, while all others are within the range from 0 to 6M. I have taken a look at the broken y-axis, but don't think it'd be something helpful in this case. I would just change the color of 16M from black to red, to indicate/stress that it is the highest number and the range is different.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use a "split" y-axis.  Something like this:

```html
<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    /* set the CSS */

    .bar {
      fill: steelblue;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <!-- load the d3.js library -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
      var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 100 },
        width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        pbottomsize = 0.66,
        ptopsize = 0.25;

      // set the ranges
      var xd = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
      var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1).domain(xd);
      var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height * pbottomsize, 0]).domain([0, 20]);
      var y1 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height * ptopsize, 0]).domain([1000000, 2000000]);

      var svg = d3
        .select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

      var g1 = svg
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + (margin.top + height * 0.33) + ')');

      var g2 = svg
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

      var data = d3.range(1, 100).map(function (d, i) {
        return {
          x: xd[Math.floor(Math.random() * xd.length)],
          y: Math.random() < 0.75 ? Math.random() * 20 : (Math.random() + 1) * 1000000,
        };
      });

      var data0 = data.filter(function(d){
        return d.y < 1000000;
      });

      var data1 = data.filter(function(d){
        return d.y > 1000000;
      })

      // append the rectangles for the bar chart
      g1
        .selectAll('.circle')
        .data(data0)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
          return x(d.x) + (x.bandwidth() / 2);
        })
        .attr('r', 10)
        .attr('cy', function (d) {
          return y(d.y);
        })
        .style('fill', 'steelblue');

      g2
        .selectAll('.circle')
        .data(data1)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
          return x(d.x) + (x.bandwidth() / 2);
        })
        .attr('r', 10)
        .attr('cy', function (d) {
          return y1(d.y);
        })
        .style('fill', 'red');

      // add the x Axis
      g1
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height * pbottomsize) + ')')
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      // add the y Axis
      g1.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(y));

      g2.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(y1).ticks(3));

      var g3 = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 70.5 + ',' + 136 + ')')

      g3.append('path')
        .attr('d', 'M 10 10 Q 20 0, 30 10 T 50 10 M 30 10 L 30 -2')
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('fill', 'none');

      g3.append('path')
        .attr('d', 'M 10 20 Q 20 10, 30 20 T 50 20 M 30 20 L 30 32')
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('fill', 'none');
        
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```